# Converting a testing notebook to a notebook

Tags: notebooks, version-10, cells, testing-and-verification

I build a testing notebook and it got too slow and unreliable with many test cases.

I want to have a new (classical) notebook with all the the inputs I have in the testing one. Is there an automatic way to do that (except for manual copy and paste)? The option `More > Convert Selection to Test` doesn't seem to have any effect on my selections.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Thanks, you should post an answer

Comment: I have the same issue. Large testing notebooks seem to become extremely slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was the first time I played with Test Notebook so maybe I missed something obvious. But it works for OP so:

```
(Composition[
            CellPrint, 
            ReplacePart[#, 2 -> "Input"] &,
            NotebookRead
           ] /@   Cells[ # ,   CellStyle -> "VerificationTest"]
)&
```

One should apply that function to the `Notebook Object` of interest.